# (php) how to pass a class method as callback in array_filter?

Tags: php, function, oop

when calling `array_filter` with a php function you just should do

```
function myFunc($e) {
    return something($e);
}
array_filter($myArray,"myFunc");
```

but how do i pass a class method? (static or non-static)
for example

```
class A {
    public function foo() {
        //code
        $a = array_filter($array,"self::myFilter");
        //or if myFilter is an instance method
        $a = array_filter($array,"this->myFilter");
    }
    public (static)? function myFilter($e) {return something($e);}
}
```

i need because i will reuse my filter function in other places in the class, i tried using anonymous functions in static variables but i get error

Comment: PHP manual page for callbacks: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: the 'duplicate' provided by the maintainers is a different question. a class method is not an object method. please read the question before you moderate, @fuzzytree and others.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work for the instance method version:

```
class A {
    public function foo() {
        $a = array_filter($array, array($this, "myFilter"));
    }
    public function myFilter($e) {return something($e);}
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php